# Joomla и CSS меню

Tags: меню, joomla, css

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста, где в данном блоке CSS кода описывается выпадение меню? А точнее меню 2 уровня выпадает вправо, а надо как и меню 1го уровня - вниз. С CSS знаком мало. Огромная просьба помочь. Пример выпадения меню можно посмотреть [ТУТ](http://saratov-cson.ru/)

JS точно не подключены для работы меню.

```
    /* Navigation */
#nav {}
#navl {}
#navr {height:40px; width: 990px; background:url(../images/mainmenu.png) 0 0 repeat-x; font-family: 'Terminal Dosis', sans-serif; margin-top: -4px;}
#nav {z-index:10; position:relative;}
#nav-left { float:left; width:120%;}
#nav-right { float:right; width:20%}
#nav ul {margin-left: 3px; padding:0; float:left;}
#nav ul li {list-style:none;float:left;height:120%;position:relative; padding:0; margin:0;}
#nav ul li a { display:block;padding:0 15px 0 15px; margin:0; line-height:40px; color:#fff; text-decoration:none;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;}
#nav ul li.active {}
#nav ul li.active a {background:#1994e2 url(../images/mainmenu-h.png) 0 0 repeat-x; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; color:#036D9E; text-shadow: #e1e1e1 0 1px; height: 30px; margin: 5px 0px 5px 1px; line-height: 30px;}
#nav ul li:hover {}
#nav ul li a:hover{ text-decoration:none; font-weight:normal; background:#1994e2 url(../images/mainmenu-h.png) 0 0 repeat-x; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; color:#036D9E; text-shadow: #e1e1e1 0 1px; height: 30px; margin: 5px 0px 5px 1px; line-height: 30px;}
#nav ul li ul {position:absolute;width:280px;left:-999em;border-top:0; margin:0; padding:0;}
#nav ul li:hover ul, #menu ul li.sfHover ul {left:0;}
#nav ul li ul li {padding:0;height:auto;width:280px; margin:0 auto; border:none; text-align: left;}
#nav ul li ul li:hover ul {left:280px; top:0}
#nav ul li:hover ul li a {text-shadow:none;}
#nav ul li:hover ul li { background:none;}
#nav ul li:hover ul li a, #nav ul li ul li a, #nav ul li.active ul li a{margin:0; padding:0 0 0 10px;height:24px;line-height:24px; background:#555;border-bottom:1px solid #3a3a3a;color:#d1d1d1; font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;text-shadow:none; -moz-border-radius: 0px; border-radius: 0px;}
#nav ul li ul li a:hover, #nav ul li ul li.active a, #nav ul li.active ul li a:hover, #nav ul li.active ul li.active a {text-align: left; padding:0 0 0 10px;height:24px;line-height:24px;background:#343434;color:#fff; font-size:12px;text-shadow:none;}
#nav ul li ul ul, #nav ul li:hover ul ul, #nav ul li:hover ul ul ul, #nav ul li:hover ul ul ul ul, #nav ul li.sfHover ul ul, #nav ul li.sfHover ul ul ul, #nav ul li.sfHover ul ul ul ul {left:-999em;}
#nav ul li ul li ul li{padding:0;height:auto;width:180px; margin:0 auto; border:none; text-align: left;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За выпал влево отвечает следующая строчка
    #nav ul li ul li:hover ul {left:280px; top:0}

Но поменяв ее вы ничего не добьетесь, если вы ходите чтобы выпадало вниз, надо еще ряд параметров переписать.

Comment: Ув. shanhaichik. Если не сложно, не подскажешь, что нужно конкретно прописать? Извиняюсь, конечно, но я CSS знаю очень плохо.

Comment: Верните на сайте прошлое меню, чтобы посмотреть.

Comment: Все вернул, просто рассматриваю другие варианты... Нет модулей меню который нужен=(

Comment: В вашем случае проще написать стиль с нуля или найти плагин вроде такого http://www.joomlan.ru/extensions-joomla/module/361-accordion-menu.html, чем менять то что есть. Если плохо в этом понимаете, то лучше заказать или попросить кого-то сделать то что вам необходимо.